# Text being truncated in TextView with width set to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I'm trying to create a simple component in my layout, where there are two TextViews horizontally next to each other. The one on the right should start where the one on the left finishes. My code for this is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I programmatically set the text on each TextView after the view has rendered. However, sometimes the text does not display correctly in the first TextView- I can see that the width has been set correctly, as the second TextView is not next to it, but the text is truncated rather than using the space. If I lock/unlock the device to refresh the screen then the text displays correctly (without the widths of the TextViews changing).

I've tried changing this to use a RelativeLayout, but I see the same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Although i dont understant what exactly you mean, would suggest you to use weightSum property in the parent view and android:layout_weight in child views. The same allows to put many child views inside a parent view with respect to ratio (like navigation tabs).

for eg :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" /> //60% width

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" 
        android:layout_weight="0.6" /> //40% width

</LinearLayout>
```

also, dont forget to put the width if child views as 0dp. as that will result in ignoring the calculations regarding the width of view. or you can set the width of child view as "match_parent" as well. any other property to width will not work. (and if you want half matchparent for both child views set layout_width to 0.5 both views.. ithink thats obvious to note)

Hopw it helps.